# Control data flow in Pentaho transformation with variables

Tags: variables, etl, pentaho, jobs, pentaho-design-studio

I want to control data flow in pentaho transformation files with system variables. I found a component called 'simple evaluation' which is exactly what I want, however it can only be used in job files. 
I have gone through component-tree of transformation from spoon but cannot find any one like 'simple evaluation'.

Can anyone give me some idea, how to make it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC you can't use variables in the filter rows step.  That would probably be a worthy 
change request to raise in jira.pentaho.com

So, simply use a "Get Variables" step to get the variable into the stream
and then use the filter rows step. ( or switch/case depending on complexity )